# How to run a macro automatically when the selections of pivot tables are changed

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I got a pivot table with shows the data for Quarters in it, and a macro that performs some calculations based on the data in pivot table. So now I want to run the Macro automatically when I changed the selection of pivot items, like if select Quarter1 , it shows the values for Q1 and run the macro automatically so that it calculate the values for Q1, and same for all selections including the multiple selections..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put something like this in the code module of the worksheet with the pivot table:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

' Call your macro here

End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 Yup. I got it confused with `Worksheet.PivotTableAfterValueChange Event` LOL

Comment: Thanks mate, Its just very simple , I made it mess by doing lot of things to this before... Thanks again , this one working great.. :)

Comment: Hi Doug, Can you help me with my other question regarding the pivotitems into seperate cells please??

Comment: Glad to help.  I left a comment on your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10785343/293078.

Comment: Is there a C# (Excel Interop) example for tapping into a PivotTable's change event? I need to rerun some "hide" code when the user filters a PivotTable.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon there is, at least for the PivotTableUpdate event discussed here. For general how-to see this: http://www.bettersolutions.com/csharp/excel-interop/event-handling.htm. For the `PivotTableUpdate` syntax see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheet_events.aspx

Comment: @DougGlancy: Thanks, I don't see how this can work, though, on a dead/petrified .xlsx file. Is it possible to embed the event handler code in the .xlsx file so that it actually would fire? I doubt it, but am not sure.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, no you can't embed it in an existing xlsx. The best you can do for an existing file is create a .Net addin with an application-level event that then checks if the workbook that fired it is your xlsx. The user would then have to install the addin. Not trivial, obviously.

Comment: @DougGlancy: Interesting concept - do you know of any examples that show how to do this?

Comment: Here's something that looks good: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668205.aspx. I'm sure there's plenty of good resources out there.