# Trigger Macro with Slicer Change

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm trying to modify data in a cell range when changing the selection in a slicer.
Can this be done in Excel for Mac?

Comment: Probably. Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800134/how-to-run-a-macro-automatically-when-the-selections-of-pivot-tables-are-changed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is! As @BigBen had already mentioned, it is possible via the event Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate. This is also supported by Excel for Mac.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    
End Sub
```

It is important that the code is defined in the corresponding sheet module

Comment: This only works for pivot table slicers, it does not work for Table slicers unfortunatelly.